# Does the limit exist if a function approaches a limit where it is discontinuous??

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

[image]

If the function is discontinuous at $x=0$ and$f(0)=4.5$ . And as $x$ approaches $0$, the value of function nears $3$.

Does the limit in this case exist?

Imho ,it does and equals $3$ but one of my friend disagreed.

I'd be grateful if someone even hints at my error.

Thank you.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Do you mean the function is discontinuous at$0$ or simply that it is not defined at $0$?

Comment: @Dear Bernard, it is discontinues and has a value of $4.5$ at $x=0$.

Comment: How are limits defined in your book? Does "$\varepsilon$-$\delta$" mean anything to you?

Comment: @Dear Arthur, no I don't understand it however I know that when we try to compute a limit we let our independent variable go forever closer to the point of interest and then we observe to what value the function is approaching. In this question I mentally imagined that as I near $x=0$ the function grows closer and closer to $3$ and hence that might be the limit. I also for a concrete answer assumed my function to be $y= x +2$ $x<0$ and got as $x$--> 0 $y$-->2 even if the function be discontinuous.

Comment: It's also called removable discontinuity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit exists, and is $3$. The fact that the limit is not the value of the function there is what tells you the function isn't continuous.

Comment: Thank you Mr Ethan Bolker.

Answer (score 1):

The limit exists and is 3. As I recall form my first year of calculus (Analysis?):  *If a function f is real-valued, then the limit of f at p is L if and only if both the right-handed limit and left-handed limit of f at p exist and are equal to L.*    $lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}f(x)=lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}f(x)=3$